# Python cannot open file

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
data = open("/home/mia/Desktop/results/all-nodup.txt", "r")
fd = open("/home/mia/Desktop/results/all-filter.txt", "w")

last_time = 0.0
last_ip = None
last_hash = None
row = data.read()

for line in row:
      timestamp, ip, hash_value = line.split()

      if ip==last_ip and hash_value==last_hash:  

           if float(timestamp) - float(last_time) >= 5.0:
             fd.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (str(timestamp), str(ip), str(hash_value))) 
             last_time, last_ip, last_hash = timestamp, ip, hash_value
      else:
           fd.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (str(timestamp), str(ip), str(hash_value)))   
           last_time, last_ip, last_hash = timestamp, ip, hash_value

fd.close()
```

This is my entire code, I go to results/ directory to run: `python filter.py` 
I got an error message: `python: can't open file 'filter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

But every other scripts can be executed, so python works fine, maybe I should import something in this case?

Comment: Without changing directory, what does `ls filter.py` show? How about `head -1 filter.py` ?

Answer (score 1):

python can't even find your filter.py script file, so changing your code is useless. To fix that you'll either need to:

- put `filter.py` inside `results/` directory
- use absolute path, e.g. `python /path/to/script/filter.py`
- figure out the correct relative path, e.g. `python ../../blah/filter.py`
- put the path where filter.py resides into your PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

That's because `filter.py` is not in the directory you're running the command in.

Try `python /path/to/filter.py`. You can also use relative paths, for example, if the file is one directory up, use `python ../filter.py`.

Comment: @Lie Ryan I am 1000000% sure it is in the same directory

Comment: @ShawnChin yes, pretty sure, that's why it's so strange

Comment: @manxing: the error message says there isn't a file named filter.py in the current directory; since you're changing directory, the script file is no longer in your current directory

Comment: `filter.py` is in `/home/mia/Desktop/results`, and that's also where you run the command? (don't mean to be condescending, but this is really strange and we need to properly rule this out before hunting for other possibilities)